# angular 5 weird behavior when calling function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using angular 5,
I call denoFormat(item["DENOMINATION"])
I get the following error stack

> vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'denoFormat' of undefined
>       at main.e31e50ee66f46596cba1.bundle.js:1
>       at Function.g.map.g.collect (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at e._next (main.e31e50ee66f46596cba1.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.T14+.e.__tryOrUnsub (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.T14+.e.next (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.T14+.e._next (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.T14+.e.next (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.L8VJ.e._next (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.T14+.e.next (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.s (vendor.91392bd4e66ade432f98.bundle.js:1)

If I were to use item["DENOMINATION"] no error occurs. Can someone explain what's going on?

```
 var _data =  [ { DENOMINATION: 0, FIT: 0, UNFIT: 0},
        { DENOMINATION: 1, FIT: 2157, UNFIT: 1842},
        { DENOMINATION: 2, FIT: 2455, UNFIT: 2031 }
  ];

  var arr = [];
  arr.push(_.map(this._data ,function(item){
    if (((item["FIT"] + item["UNFIT"]) != 0) && (item["DENOMINATION"] <= 5)){
      return {"name": this.denoFormat(item["DENOMINATION"]) ,"series": [
      {
        "name": "FIT",
        "value": item["FIT"]
      },
      {
        "name": "UNFIT",
        "value": item["UNFIT"]
      }
    ]}
  } else{
    return;
}
}));
      denoFormat(n){
        var val;
        switch (n){
          case 0:
          val = 1000;
          break;
          case 1:
          val = 5000;
          break;
          etc.
        }
        return val;
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you have to use an arrow function to prevent the scope changing.

```
arr.push(_.map(this._data , (item) => {
    // ...
    this.denoFormat()
    //...
}
```

Comment: will mark as answered when allowed to. Thanks a lot.